# Eigenvalues of a matrix in a partial ordering

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, order-theory

If $A \succeq B$ for $A, B \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times n}$, then will $\lambda_{i}(A) \geq \lambda_{i}(B)$ for all $i \leq n$? Intuition says yes, but I don't know how to properly show this.

Comment: What is this partial ordering? i.e. what is the meaning of: $A \succeq B$

Comment: If $A$ and $B$ are symmetric and if $A \succeq B$ means $A - B$ is positive semidefinite, then I think your assertion is correct and should follow from the minimax principle.

Comment: The partial ordering $A \succeq B$ does indeed mean that $A - B$ is positive definite! Where can I learn more about this minimax principle?

Comment: @E9101 See [this Wiki post](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Min-max_theorem). You could also prove this result using [Weyl's matrix inequalities](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weyl%27s_inequality#Weyl's_inequality_about_perturbation) (which can in turn be proved as a consequence of the min-max theorem).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since $A\succeq B$, then $\dfrac{x^TAx}{x^Tx} \ge \dfrac{x^TBx}{x^Tx}$ for all $x\in \mathbb{R}^n\setminus\{0\}$. In particular, for every subspace $U$ of $\mathbb{R}^n$ of dimension $i \le n$,
$$\max_{x\in U\setminus\{0\}} \frac{x^TAx}{x^T x} \ge \max_{x\in U\setminus\{0\}} \frac{x^TBx}{x^Tx} \ge \min_{\dim V = i}\max_{x\in V\setminus\{0\}} \frac{x^TBx}{x^Tx}$$where the minimum is extended over all $i$-dimensional vector subspaces $V$ of $\mathbb{R}^n$. By the minimax principle, the latter expression equals $\lambda_i(B)$. Since $U$ is arbitrary, another application of the minimax principle yields $\lambda_i(A) \ge \lambda_i(B)$.